# Using Inverse sine/ arc sin (math.asin) function in python to find the missing angles of a right angle triangle

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make a python program that finds a missing angle of a right-angled triangle. It takes an input of two sides which are not the Hypotenuse and then calculates the hypotenuse. To find one of the missing angles.

Here is how we can do it in real life...

[This is an image showing what I am trying to do, I want to find the θ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfADF.jpg)

To do this we have to inverse sine Opposite-angle/Hypotenuse

You can find about the method [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-inverse-sin-cos-tan.html)

I wrote this python code but it is not giving the right answer...

```
import math

print("Enter The X:",end="")
x = round(float(input()),1)
#The adjusten side

print("Enter The Z:",end="")
z = round(float(input()),1)
#Getting the Opposite side 

h = round(math.sqrt((x*x)+(z*z)),1)
# Finding out the Hypotenuse

m = round(z/h,2)
# Opp/H

#Till here the code works perfect giving the right answers but from here I guess I am doing something wrong

a = math.asin(m)
# inverse sine the Opp/H 

print("Go to "+ str(a) +" degree")
#Printing the answer
```

Like if I give the input as this (adjacent side)X = 4.0, (Opp side)Z = 2.8 [Here is the solution for this case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtmEm.png)

'a' should be 35 degrees which is the inverse sine of 0.57 approximately, but it is giving out 0.6065058552130869 degrees as the answer 'a'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct answer in radians, you have to convert the radians to degrees.
This can be done by a math.degrees call

```
a = math.degrees(math.asin(m))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am really a newbie in programming and trigonometry...